# How to Ignore first column in MySQL query saving txt to database?

Tags: php, mysql

```
I have txt file
text1|text2|text3|text4,
text1|text2|text3|text4,
text1|text2|text3|text4,
text1|text2|text3|text4,
text1|text2|text3|text4,

 ("LOAD DATA  INFILE '1.txt' INTO TABLE `main`
                    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
                    LINES TERMINATED BY ','
                    ");
```

`main` table view is
id value1 value2 value3 value4

everything works ok

> i need to ignore first column (`id`) !!

How to change mysql query to insert

```
text1 to value1
text2 to value2
text3 to value3
```

etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IGNORE, like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.txt' INTO TABLE test IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Comment: He doesn't want to skip the first line he wants to skip the id column on each line.

Comment: Oh you're right but its already answered.